# Adding a custom integration to a local API in Ghost Blog

Tags: ghost-blog

I'm new to Ghost and I would like to add a contact form on my website.

After some research, I found some third party integrations like Zappier, Formspree, JotForm and others...the thing is that I don't want to rely on an external service, or pay for such a simple thing as a contact form!

I want to run my own API on my server (on a specific port) and integrate it into Ghost.

Is it possible? If so, what's the simplest and safest way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but not recommended. Changing the core of Ghost means you're effectively opting out of future updates. Services like Formspree, Google Forms and others will do the job much better without the risk of breaking your installation